# Semi-flexível: Junto, separado, com ou sem hífen

Tags: ortografia

Estava eu redigindo um artigo no qual eu precisava usar a palavra "semi" e "flexível" (vou deixar separadas por enquanto).

Tive dúvida se eu juntava com um hífen ou não então fui pesquisar e vi que, pelo menos no caso particular de "semi", só junta se a palavra a ser conectada começar com a mesma vogal que anterior termina, "h", "r" ou "s".

Bom, a palavra que vou usar não se enquadra nisso, então seria sem.

Daí, nessa revisão bem superficial, feita no Word mesmo, mais pra pegar possíveis palavras digitadas erradas, "semi flexível", separado, acusou o hífen como requerido. Eu coloquei o hífen e o clipe de papel idiota informa que eu tenho que remover o hífen. (dafuq)

Beleza, meu Word é antigo (2003) e a análise que ele faz não é lá muito precisa. Mas aqui mesmo no editor, num browser, "semi-flexível", com hífen, não grifou de vermelho, então não estaria errado.

> O uso dessa palavra em particular foi por precisar descrever as guelras externas de um animal marinho que parecem, juro, a capa do Batman (do Nolan) quando enrijecem. Não é rígida, mas nem 100% flexível, e não sei se seriam cartilogionosas ou não, então optei pelo "semi"

Comment: Achei isso: https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/semi Exprime a noção de metade, meio, quase (ex.: semibreve).

Nota: é seguido de hífen quando o segundo elemento começa por h, i, r ou s (ex.: semi-herbáceo, semi-interno, semi-recta, semi-sábio).

"semi-", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/semi- [consultado em 13-01-2018].

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente é melhor não deixar um programa desatualizado prevalecer sobre a regra gramatical.

Ainda que esse fosse um critério, meu navegador, Firefox, com o *add-on* "Verificador Ortográfico para Português do Brasil" versão 2.5-3.2.13 (atualizado em outubro de 2017) acusa a versão sem hífen (de acordo, portanto, com a regra) como a correta:

[image]

Comment: Nunca disse que sim. E, de fato, ainda mencionei que a Verificação **Ortográfica** feita com o Word era mais pra pegar erros de digitação que ocorrem vez ou outra por digitar rápido com meu braço, punhos e dedos com problemas. Mas, é um add-on interessante, se eu usasse o Firefox, seria até uma opção.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto, não tive a intenção de ofender, em minha primeira frase.

Comment: Oras, mas tá desatualizado mesmo. Por que seria uma ofensa XD

Comment: @BrunoAugusto :-) Ótimo que não tenha sido!